# Software for video subscription service

Tags: ecommerce, recommendations

I'd like to sell instructional videos over the web.  Primarily, I'd like uses to subscribe to the site and be allowed access to videos over the internet.  Secondarily, I might sell DVDs for those who have poor internet connections or would like a physical copy, or possibly I'd sell eBooks and the like in the future.

Regarding the subscriptions:

- I'd like a system that automatically sends out e-mails when it is time to renew
- I'd like to be able to offer free trials
- Users without a free trial or subscription should not be able to access the content

  - Incidentally, I plan to host videos on my current web host and move them to a CDN when volume (and capital) make this a good idea.  While I have no intention to go crazy with the DRM, it seems expedient not to directly link to the files -- how can I link to them indirectly?
- It would be nice to support multiple payment processors -- specifically, I'd like to avoid a PayPal only approach.

Are there any web applications (or plugins) you'd recommend for something like this?  While I've set up and administered several web technologies, I've never done anything with e-commerce.  I see there are possibilities like osCommerce, one friend recommends using WordPress with plugins, and it really appears that for any given CMS, you can graft on components like this, although I imagine that not all are created equal.

As I'm not tied to a particular web application (and, while open source software that can run on a LAMP [p=perl, python, php] stack is preferable), I'd like to make a good choice at the beginning.

Comment: Did the plugin work for you?

Comment: @Christopher - I'm afraid that project has been put on hold and I've been too busy to try it.  It sure sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run wordpress, I would recommend you get [wp eStore](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-estore-plugin-complete-solution-to-sell-digital-products-from-your-wordpress-blog-securely-1059) plugin. It does pretty much all the things you want. Check out the demo tutorials.